# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException in WebAPI + IQueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate, asp.net-web-api

I created a new MVC4 web api project to expose the entities over HTTP. Since I wanted the query to be executed against the database and not in-memory I enabled the query support

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.EnableQuerySupport();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

here is my IQueryable. I am using the Repository pattern to retrieve data using NHibernate.

```
public class TradeViewController : ApiController
{
    public IQueryable<TradeView> Get()
    {
        return new TradeViewRepository().GetQueryable();
    }
}
```

When I try to test the controller I get following exception

> > System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
> >     Parameter name: index

Here is my test

```
public void Get()
{
    TradeViewController controller = new TradeViewController();

    // Act
    var result = controller.Get();
    var count = result.Take<TradeView>(10).Count();

    Assert.AreEqual(10, count);
}
```

Also in general, is it possible to use LINQ queries against controllers in WebAPI?

Thanks

Comment: What `index` is the error referring to? Are you sure the repository works without issues?

Comment: Are you sure you actually have 10 records for `Take`?

Comment: Yes Repository returns the records fine and there are more than a million records in the table so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Sounds like something is wrong with the repository, can you post the code of the repo?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember this correctly, the OData pipeline in Web Api does sometimes create queries and expects stuff which NHibernate does not allow or even the NHibernate Linq provider does not support/understand.

So just enabling the query support is not enough to get your NHibernate driven API controller working...

Maybe this nuget helps you get your stuff running:
https://github.com/pvginkel/NHibernate.OData

Or try to google for some blogs, you'll find at least some talks around that...
Otherwise if this is all too much, simply use entity framework... The whole asp.net odata implementation is done for and with entity framework ;)